# Meteor - {{#if template}} is current

Tags: meteor, template-engine, iron-router

I wonder is there any function to check if specific template is on page. 
For example i have following:

- -header
- -yield
- --postPage
- --many others

And when postPage is opened i want to display link in header template. 
Maybe smth similar to {{#if currentUser}}button{{/if}}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a way to see all templates currently being rendered, presumably there is at least a private API for it, but you could do:

```
displayLinks = new ReactiveVar(false);

Template.postPage.onRendered(function() {
  displayLinks.set(true);
});

Template.postPage.onDestroyed(function() {
  displayLinks.set(false);
});

Template.header.helpers({
  displayLinks: function() {
    return displayLinks.get();
  }
});
```

Basically you are setting a reactive variable to true when postPage is displayed and false when it is taken off the DOM.
Then {{#if displayLinks}} ... {{/if}} in your header.

You will need to

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

if you aren't already using them.

Comment: Is it not better to store this variable in session ?

Comment: @KimRis session variables are not advisable where possible as they can easily found and manipulated in the client session.  Also these will persist between different pages of the of your app, whereas a session variable when attached to the template's data context will not

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add unto shambles' response. (Great response BTW)

If you have many templates want want to know which ones are displayed without implementing the onRendered/onDestroyed for each template, you can do it using the following code:

```
displayLinks = new ReactiveVar(false);

_.each(["header", "yield", "postPage", "etc"], function(t) {
  Template[t].onRendered(function () {
    displayLinks[t].set(true);
  });

  Template[t].onDestroyed(function () {
    displayLinks[t].set(false);
  });
});
```